# How to disable Save button, if there is no edit made in input field using Angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, ngmodel

I am using Angular8 application and in this i have added inline edit using ngModel, but in this i have to keep Save button disabled, if there is no change in the input fields, if there is any change among 3 fields then save button should be enabled.

HTML:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let contact of yearManagement">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="text-capitalize">
          <ng-container *ngIf="editableRow !== contact.id; else newDeb">
            {{contact.policyTypeName}}
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template #newDeb>
            <input [(ngModel)]="contact.policyTypeName" />
          </ng-template>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ng-container *ngIf="editableRow !== contact.id; else newDeb1">
            {{contact.quotes}}
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template #newDeb1>
            <input [(ngModel)]="contact.quotes" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange(oldVal, $event); oldVal = $event;"/>
          </ng-template>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ng-container *ngIf="editableRow !== contact.id; else newDeb2">
            {{contact.policyCT}}
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template #newDeb2>
            <input [(ngModel)]="contact.policyCT" />
          </ng-template>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ng-container *ngIf="editableRow !== contact.id; else newDeb3">
            {{contact.writtenPremium}}
          </ng-container>
          <ng-template #newDeb3>
            <input [(ngModel)]="contact.writtenPremium" />
          </ng-template>
        </td>
        <td class="width125">
          <ng-container *ngIf="editableRow == contact.id;">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table" title="close"
            (click)="onCloseEvent(contact)"
           >close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table" title="close" (click)="onSave(contact)" [disabled]="disableSubmit()"
              >save</button>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="editableRow !== contact.id;">

            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table ml-1" title="Edit"
          (click)="[editableRow = contact.id,onEditEvent(contact)]">Edit</button>
          </ng-container>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table ml-1" title="Delete"
                      (click)="deleteCommitment(contact)">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

TS:

```
 public disableSubmit() {
    let disabled = true;
    const keys = Object.keys();
    keys.forEach(key => {
      if () {
        disabled = false;
        return;
      }
    });
    return disabled;
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ad1xiv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: How you want to define the change. What if user has enter "Hello" and then again removing it and entering it again "Hello", Will it be count as change?

Comment: jus want to track change, if user types hello and removes it means save to be enabled, bcz there is some change in input know so

Comment: i am ok with anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand the issue and made a few modifications, it did work as expected.

**First**: define a boolean variable called disabled

```
selectedRow: any;
disable: boolean;
public onEditEvent(event) {
  this.disable = true;
  this.selectedRow = { ...event };
  this.editCommitment = event;
 }
```

The first time when the edit is clicked, it will be true, and the save button will be disabled.

**Second** change the **onChangeModel** function, ***check if the value in the field is changed, if yes, re-activate the save button otherwise it will be disabled.***

```
oldValue: string;
onModelChange(oldval, event) {
 if (event) {
    this.disable = false;
    console.log(oldval, event);
    if (this.oldValue != event) {
    }
    this.oldValue = event;
  }
 }
```

**lastly** return the valuable disable in the getter function

```
public get disableSubmit() {
  return this.disable;
}
```

Now call this getter function on the save button

```
       <button
          class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table"
          title="close"
          (click)="onSave(contact)"
          [disabled]="disableSubmit"
        >
          save
        </button>
```